# filter the json data and draw the nvd3 chart using filtered data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

```
d3.json('http://www.mocky.io/v2/57d14d2f100000cd19208e19', function (error, historicalBarChart) {

(function () {


    nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value })
        .staggerLabels(true)
        //.staggerLabels(historicalBarChart[0].values.length > 8)
        .showValues(true)
        .duration(250)
        .height(300)
        .width(400)
        ;


        var filtered1=historicalBarChart[0].values.filter(function(d) { return d.value > 15;});

    console.log(filtered1); // getting filtered json here

    d3.select('#chart2 svg')
        .datum(filtered1) // doesn't render chart for filtered json
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;

    });
})();
});
```

I am trying to filter the data for values greater than 15 in the api data and draw the chart.But the data is not getting filtered and the chart is not rendered due to non availability of data. How to filter the data and display the nvd3 charts ? Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Your test set (`http://www.mocky.io/v2/57d14d2f100000cd19208e19`) doesn't contain objects with `label` and `value` keys.
It contains an array which has only one object, which contains a `value` key.

So you should use : 
`var filtered1 = historicalBarChart[0].values.filter(..)` instead of just `historicalBarChart.filter(...)`

Comment: The json is filtered.. and the chart  renders but with the whole unfiltered json...

Comment: updated the code as per your recommendations... even though the json is filtered the chart does not render...I think maybe its due to the format in which the json is returned after filtering...there is also one error in console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"...

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot stumbled upon this solution,putting the filtered data in the json format needed by the nvd3 does the trick..code to do so is below..

var filtered = [{ key: "Cumulative Return", values: filtered1 }]